# Twilio Flex - Adding Agents With Restricted Access Without Single Sign On SSO

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

Is there a way to add agents to my Flex project without single sign on enabled? Our business model requires us to connect clients with agents who are independent contractors. From both a practical and legal standpoint, we can't provide them with something like an Active Directory or Gmail account.

When I add agents "locally", the lowest level of access I can grant to an agent is *developer*. This role allows agents to make changes to our underlying application.

Is there a way to grant users access as agents without SSO? If there is no way to do this through the UI, I am open to a solution that requires a custom JavaScript / React plugin.

Comment: SSO is a requirement with Flex (non admin login role), Configuring SSO and IdP in Flex - https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/sso-configuration#can-i-log-into-flex-agent-desktop-without-an-identity-provider. OKTA is fairly straight forward to set-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to Twilio support and non-SSO agent assignment is not an option